# Can I ask two related but distinct questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

After I asked a question about SQL ([Is there an embedded database protocol which is faster than SQLite for VERY large databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10711670/425458)), a more specific, but still related, question occurred to me:

> ### Do any embedded/serverless database protocols have a larger feature set than SQLite?
>
> Are there are any embedded database protocols with a larger feature set than SQLite? For example, postgresql, which is not an embedded protocol, supports multiple indexing methods (btree, hash, gist, and gin), whereas SQLite only supports a default method (b-trees, I think). Is there an embedded protocol which does support the postgresql indexing methods? Are these indexing methods, or any other features which SQLite lacks, important for optimizing the performance of large databases?

Can I post this question as well, or is it considered bad form to ask two so closely related questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can you give me a list of things that meet this criteria?

is not a good question for Stack Overflow.

> Are these indexing methods, or any other features which SQLite lacks, important for optimizing the performance of large databases?

is also a separate, and extremely broad, question. You shouldn't sneak it in at the end of a more specific, answerable question.

So, in this instance, no, you shouldn't ask that question as stated.

**In General**, it's fine to post multiple related questions, as long as they are actually distinct, you put effort into the questions, and they are otherwise appropriate for the site.

Comment: Do make sure that you ask separate questions as *separate questions*, though. One question per question.

Comment: That all sounds reasonable, and I'll be sure to abide by it. I'm still left with my original problem though: SQLite seems to be the default embedded SQL implementation, but that doesn't mean that it's the best. I would like to try out some of the non-SQLite SQL features that I've read about, such as hash indexing and SPARSE tables, to see if they can help tune the performance of my database.

Comment: I keep running into these "broadness of scope" issues on SO all of the dang time, so apparently I don't quite get the related subtleties. You seem like you're on top of it, though. Can you help me out with an example of how to rephrase my question such that it will meet the SO guidelines and still be likely to elicit the name of at least one (or would "at most one" be more appropriate?) embedded database that meets my needs?

Comment: @tel See [Stack Overflow is not a recommendation engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/128562#128562) and the linked posts.  In general, you need to pose the question as a specific problem you need to solve. A possible formulation of your question: `I need to do X real-world task and [this SQLite setup] isn't working. I need an embedded database, and I know that feature Y from PostgreSQL would make this work. I have looked for an embedded database that has feature Y but can't find one. How can I solve this problem?`